# Java compile time needed dependency causing problem in job

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a project that uses a dependency only for compilation and it will not use it on the production environment for some configurations (Never make reference to those classes in that dependecy). That dependency has only snapshot version and I cannot use snapshot on release versions on Jenkins jobs (company rules). How can I achieve this? Is there work-arounds to handle this?
Setting scope to provided has no effect on build process.

Project A (release) -- depends --> Project B (snapshot)

There is no way of getting release of project B.

Comment: Create a release yourself?

Comment: First thought create a release of it because it's needed for building your code... furthermore I would ask why do you use such code which is needed for compilation but not used for production env. Sounds like a strange thing to be honest?? can you explain that more in detail?

Comment: Depending on the license of Project B, you could "unpack" it's contents and re-package it with a new (release) version. Or copy the classes you need into Project A.

Comment: as you don't need it on production, could you create a profile in your maven file and run 2 builds? One build for your non-production propouses and the release one.

Comment: Same module used in two different computer. In one computer, that dependency is provided by the environment and dependency will be used in my project actively. In other computer, that dependency will not be referenced in my module and also environment will not provide that jar.

Comment: @btafarelo release still not gonna let me use snapshot in any profile.

Comment: Put the snapshot in a profile is trackable and it limit its usage. Anything else from their sight will be bypassing their policy as the dependency isn't provided as a release officially. Repack the lib inside your app might be the only solution possible but I considere it as a "cheat". It will depend if they will accept or just no one cares since there's no snapshot in a pom.